# Grammar: Question tags

Tags: question-tags

Kevin dislikes eating tomatoes, does/doesn't he?

Should the correct answer be 'does he' as 'dislikes' makes the first part of the statement negative? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise. _Dislikes_ does not make the first part of the statement negative. Disliking something, just like hating something, is an active, positive [as in non-negated] verb. Its **meaning** is associated with negative values, but that doesn’t make the verb itself negative in form. The negative would be _doesn’t dislike_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's a bit harsh old bean. Normally any negative word will make the sentence negative, we don't specifically need the auxiliary to be negated: "There are no opportunities, are there?"  or "We seldom go there, do we?" It seems that although it's not a rocket-science question, it deserves a decent answer  - perhaps from you ;)

Comment: @Araucaria But _dislike_ isn’t a negative word—no verb is (at least none that I can think of). It’s just that _dislike_ has a meaning with negative feelings associated with it. That’s nothing to do with grammar. There are more interesting and less intuitive cases (like _seldom_ or and similar adverbs that limit more than they actually negate), but this isn’t one of them, I don’t think.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to consult the following Wiki article under the subtitle [Balanced vs unbalanced tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question).

**A. Kevin dislikes eating tomatoes, doesn't he?**

This would be asked when checking on a known or suspected fact, e.g.

> A: Would you and Kevin like to come round for lunch tomorrow?
>
> B: Yes, that would be really nice.
>
> A: Kevin dislikes eating tomatoes, doesn't he?
>
> B: That's right: In fact he's allergic to them.
>
> A: Okay, I'll make sure not to use any tomato in the cooking.

The above is a statement followed by a request for confirmation. It is a ***balanced*** tag question.

**B. Kevin dislikes eating tomatoes, does he?**

This would be said in a spirit of indignation or disapproval, e.g.

> M: Why isn't Kevin eating his tomato soup?
>
> N: He says he doesn't like tomatoes.
>
> M: Kevin dislikes eating tomatoes, does he?
>
> N: That's what he says.
>
> M: Well tough! Tell him he has to eat his soup whether he likes it or not.
>   That's all there is.

The above is a rhetorical question. The tag is ***unbalanced***.

Comment: Remind me never to come round yours for lunch. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - They don't call me Bumble the Beadle for nothing!

Comment: It is not only used in that way. I might equally say 'Kevin dislikes tomatoes, does he?*, without any hint of disapproval at all - simply to gain confirmation. I agree that it is used in slightly different circumstances to *doesn't he* but the difference between the two is finely nuanced. Generally one would use *does he* if you had only just learned the fact.